# shared_ptr member and copy constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm writing a C++ library and would like one of its classes to be implicitly shared. Unfortunately I'm getting a bit confused with its implementation. I want to use `std::shared_ptr` to store the data and I'm wondering if the code below is missing anything.

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass (void);

private:
    class Data;
    std::shared_ptr<Data> mData;
};
```

---

```
// MyClass.cc
class MyClass::Data
{
public:
     Data (void) { ptr = NULL; }
    ~Data (void) { delete ptr; }
    int* ptr;
};

MyClass::MyClass (void)
    : mData (new MyClass::Data())
{
    mData->ptr = new int(5);
}
```

Looking at other people's code I noticed they added copy/move constructors/operators (using std::move, etc) and an empty destructor. One of the comments mentioned that MyClass needs an empty destructor so that MyClass::Data's destructor gets noticed by the compiler. Is any of this really necessary or is the above code good enough? are the default copy/move constructors/operators and destructors good enough?

Comment: If you want `mData` pointing data to be shared then you don't need a copy constructor and assignment operator the default ones are fine.

Comment: Why not use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for the `MyClass::Data::ptr` member?

Comment: @KerrekSB I've tried it and it looks like it's working but it's good to verify because I've been trapped by these kinds of things before.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is just an example, the actual Data class is a bit more complicated and needs an explicit destructor.

Comment: Have you tried it with more than one translation unit?

Comment: Why have a shared pointer to a pointer? That seems kind of pointless.

Comment: It will work, even doing so even with a generic shared `void` pointer: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/64ulqn). Almost always blows people's minds to see that.

Comment: One of the benefits of using RAII consistently is that you stop having to worry about copy and assignment operators and destructors, the defaults just work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. You might want to declare a copy constructor in case  you want to deep-copy the data, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a shared pointer.
The empty destructor comment is complete BS. If you don't provide a destructor, a default one will be used - in any case the destructors of the member classes will always be called.

When you see people needing to explicitly default their destructors (and assignment operators) in MyClass.cc, that's because they're using `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`. If you switch to using `std::unique_ptr<Data>`, you'll see the compiler-provided destructor etc. will barf when they can't find a definition for `~Data` in scope. But `std::shared_ptr` is not allowed to barf.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, which is why I got confused when I saw people doing this. **[Here](http://ideone.com/hYnECo)** is an example of my question in action, you can see that it works as it's suppose to.